# How to make 1 thumbnails height equal to the 2 adjacent divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 bootstrap thumbnails with text in them. 2 of the thumbnails are on the left 50% of the screen width and the 3rd is on the right 50%. The 3rd should be the height of the 2 left hand side thumbnails stacked on top of each other.

I cant get my 3rd div which takes up the right 50% of the screen to stretch the full height of the screen or the even the height of the left hand side divs.

Anyway to do this?

Here is my code

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-0">                 
            <!-- Contact with Map - START -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-Green">
                            <div>
                                    <h5>
                                        Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green 
                                        Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green 
                                        Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green 
                                        Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green Green 
                                    </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--END:  row div-->
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-Red">
                            <div>
                                    <h5>
                                       Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red 
                                       Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red 
                                       Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red 
                                       Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red Red 
                                    </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--END:  row div-->
                </div><!--END: address col div-->
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                       <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-Blue">
                            <div>
                                    <h5>
                                        Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue
                                        Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue
                                        Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue
                                        Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue
                                    </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--END:  row div-->
                </div><!--END: address col div-->
            </div><!--END: address col div-->
        </div><!--END: controlscol div-->
    </div><!--END: controls row div-->
</body>
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: sure however the fiddle doesnt lay them out the way i see them locally....i think i have built the fiddle incorrectly and not set bootstrap to be used maybe?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8cky1d5g/#

Comment: If you want bootstrap in JSFiddle, you can simply fork the bootstrap template, which bootstrap 3 is already include, and paste you code : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
.stretch-to-viewport
    height: 100vh
```

This will make your div always stretch to whatever the height of the "screen" (viewport) is. `vh` stands for viewport height.

Comment: hmmm thx Sebastian. will this render the divs over other ontrols if they are in the way.... say a footer at bottom of page?

Comment: That depends on the positioning. If they're not fixed or absolute it should be fine, you could also use `z-index` to determine how elements are laid on top of each other.